# Delete all of specific nodes in an xml file

Tags: xml

I have a very large xml file (347496 lines to be exact) and it contains a lot of elements with a specific attribute that I need to get rid of. The contents of the elements are different so Find/Replace won't work. Is there a program that can delete all of the elements for me or at least a tutorial that'll teach me to script a program to do that?

Example of one of the elements: http://pastebin.com/ECq42NE2

The element is Item and the class attribute is "ManualWeld"

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: It isn't really a programming language I'm using and I'm not using this to make a program. I just need to remove those elements of of this one file. I am fluent in C#, Java, Lua, C++ (kind of), HTML, PHP, CSS and Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Create simple console app.

Please, try this C# code:

```cs
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("input.xml"))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (reader.Name == "Item")
                {
                    if (reader.MoveToAttribute("class") && reader.Value == "ManualWeld")
                    {
                        reader.Skip();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

We need manually copy all nodes, exclude attribute.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a go

Comment: All it does is remove the class attribute it doesn't delete the actual element.

Comment: @tjpc3TheRedstoner My mistake. I thought you need only remove the attribute. Try now.

Comment: Now it just deletes all item elements and replaces them with class elements

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial task for XSL Transformation (XSLT) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item[@class='ManualWeld']" />      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**brief explanation :**

- `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`: format output with proper indentation [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)].
- `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`: strips white-space-only text nodes that might appear in elements specified by the elements attributes [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)].
- `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">...</xsl:template>`: Identity template. Copy matched nodes and attributes to the output XML, unchanged.
- `<xsl:template match="Item[@class='ManualWeld']" />`: Override identity template for `Item` elements having attribute `class` value equals `"ManualWeld"`. This is an empty template, meaning that the matched elements won't be copied to the output XML (more generally, nothing will be done by empty template to the matched elements).

**<kbd>[`Xsltransform Demo`](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHUp)</kbd>**

Do note in the demo output, that `Item` element having `class='ManualWeld'` is removed and the other elements (`root`, and another `Item` element) are preserved.

Comment: OP has very big xml file. Are there xsl-processors that not loads into memory the entire xml?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question but not in the way you would have expected. See this is an xml file of a roblox place full of ManualWelds and Welds that kept lagging up everything. So I wrote a simple Lua plugin that removed all welds in Workspace.

```
local plugin = PluginManager():CreatePlugin()
local toolbar = plugin:CreateToolbar("Remove Welds Plugin")

local button = toolbar:CreateButton(
    "Remove All Welds", 
    "Click this button to remove all welds",
    "button.png"
)

function RemoveWelds(location)
        for _, v in pairs(location:GetChildren()) do
            if v:isA("Weld") or v:isA("ManualWeld") then 
                v:remove() 
                print("Removed " .. v:GetFullName())
            else
                RemoveWelds(v)
            end
     end
end

button.Click:connect(function()
    RemoveWelds(workspace)
end)
```